I have a problem with an AHK v2 script for automating resetting runs in TBOI:Afterbirth+
Ok, so I have been trying to make a program to automate runs in Isaac. I am a begginer in AHK but not in other languages so I thought I'd give it a try with the help of ChatGPT. The thing is that I think it's filled with errors I can't diagnose because I don't know about the functions used. To put it simply I want to be able to select a character and then unless some conditions are met the run resets. I'm doing this with OCR (python script works perfectly, ChatGPT helped a bit but I ammended it) and the Screenshots with GDI+. This is the code for the ahk v2 script:
#Include "Gdip_All.ahk"  ; Asegúrate de que Gdip_All.ahk está en el mismo directorio o en el directorio Lib de AutoHotkey.

#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode(2)

GameTitle := "Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth+"
GamePath := "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth\isaac-ng.exe"
PythonPath := "C:\Python312\python.exe"  ; Ruta completa al ejecutable de Python
PythonScriptPath := "C:\Users\arted\OneDrive - unizar.es\Escritorio\AutoHardIsaac\Images.py"
ScreenshotFilename := "isaac.png"
ScreenshotDestPath := "C:\Users\arted\OneDrive - unizar.es\Escritorio\AutoHardIsaac\" . ScreenshotFilename
LogFilePath := "C:\Users\arted\OneDrive - unizar.es\Escritorio\AutoHardIsaac\ahk_log.txt"  ; Archivo de log para depuración

; Inicializar GDI+
pToken := Gdip_Startup()
if !pToken
{
    MsgBox("Error: No se pudo iniciar GDI+.")
    ExitApp()
}

; Agregar mensaje de inicio de ejecución al archivo de log
FileAppend("Inicio del script de AutoHotkey.n", LogFilePath)

; Mostrar el orden de los personajes en el juego
MsgBox("Elige un número según el orden de los personajes:n1. Isaacn2. Magdalenen3. Cainn4. Judasn5. ??? (Blue Baby)n6. Even7. Samsonn8. Azazeln9. Lazarusn10. Edenn11. The Lostn12. Lilithn13. Apollyonn14. Aleatorio", "Orden de Personajes", 0)

; Preguntar al usuario para seleccionar el personaje
IB := InputBox("Introduce el número del personaje que deseas usar (del 1 al 14):", "Selección de Personaje", "w300 h150"), Personaje := IB.Value, ErrorLevel := IB.Result="OK" ? 0 : IB.Result="CANCEL" ? 1 : IB.Result="Timeout" ? 2 : "ERROR"
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox("Cancelaste la selección de personaje.")
    FileAppend("Usuario canceló la selección de personaje.n", LogFilePath)
    ExitApp()
}

; Convertir la entrada a número
Personaje := Trim(Personaje)
FileAppend("Personaje seleccionado: " Personaje "n", LogFilePath)

; Abrir el juego si no está ya activo
if !WinExist(GameTitle)
{
    Run(GamePath)
    FileAppend("Intentando abrir el juego.n", LogFilePath)
    ErrorLevel := !WinWait(GameTitle, , 10)
    if !WinActive(GameTitle)
    {
        ToolTip("Error: No se pudo abrir el juego.")
        Sleep(5000)
        ToolTip()  ; Ocultar el ToolTip
        FileAppend("Error: No se pudo abrir el juego.n", LogFilePath)
        Sleep(3000)
        ExitApp()
    }
}

Sleep(7000)  ; Espera para que el juego cargue completamente
FileAppend("Juego cargado.n", LogFilePath)

if !WinActive(GameTitle)
{
    WinActivate(GameTitle)
    Sleep(100)
    FileAppend("Juego activado.n", LogFilePath)
}

; Automatizar el proceso de inicio desde los créditos
Send("{Enter down}")
Sleep(500)
Send("{Enter up}")
Sleep(1500)

Send("{Enter down}")
Sleep(500)
Send("{Enter up}")
Sleep(1500)

Send("{Right down}")  ; Mover a la derecha para seleccionar el save 2
Sleep(500)
Send("{Right up}")
Sleep(500)

Send("{Enter down}") ; Selecciona el save 2
Sleep(500)
Send("{Enter up}")
Sleep(1500)

Send("{Up down}") ; Mover hacia arriba para seleccionar "New Run"
Sleep(500)
Send("{Up up}")
Sleep(500)

Send("{Enter down}") ; Entra en la selección de personajes
Sleep(500)
Send("{Enter up}")
Sleep(1500)

; Seleccionar personaje basado en la entrada del usuario
Switch Personaje
{
    Case "1":  ; Isaac (default, no movement needed)
        ; No se hace nada, ya que Isaac es el personaje seleccionado por defecto
    Case "2":  ; Magdalene
        Send("{Right down}")  ; Mover una vez a la derecha
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "3":  ; Cain
        Send("{Right down 2}") ; Mover dos posiciones a la derecha
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "4":  ; Judas
        Send("{Right down 3}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "5":  ; ??? (Blue Baby)
        Send("{Right down 4}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "6":  ; Eve
        Send("{Right down 5}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "7":  ; Samson
        Send("{Right down 6}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "8":  ; Azazel
        Send("{Right down 7}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "9":  ; Lazarus
        Send("{Right down 8}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "10":  ; Eden
        Send("{Right down 9}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "11":  ; The Lost
        Send("{Right down 10}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "12":  ; Lilith
        MsgBox("Lilith aún no está desbloqueada. Por favor, elige otro personaje.")
        FileAppend("Lilith aún no está desbloqueada. Salida del script.n", LogFilePath)
        ExitApp()
    Case "13":  ; Apollyon
        Send("{Right down 12}")
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Case "14":  ; Aleatorio
        Send("{Right down 13}") ; Seleccionar el personaje aleatorio
        Sleep(250)
        Send("{Right up}")
    Default: 
        MsgBox("Personaje no válido. Elige un número entre 1 y 14.")
        FileAppend("Error: Personaje no válido seleccionado.n", LogFilePath)
        ExitApp()
}

if !WinActive(GameTitle)
{
    WinActivate(GameTitle)
    Sleep(100)
}
Send("{Enter down}") ; Confirmar selección de personaje y comenzar la run
Sleep(500)
Send("{Enter up}")
Sleep(2500)

Loop
{
    ; Asegúrate de que el juego esté activo
    if !WinActive(GameTitle)
    {
        WinActivate(GameTitle)
        Sleep(100)
    }
    Sleep(1200)

    ; Capturar usando DWM Thumbnails
    hwnd := WinGetID(GameTitle)
    DwmRegisterThumbnail(hwnd, 0, hwndThumb)
    DwmQueryThumbnailSourceSize(hwndThumb, Width, Height)

    hbm := Gdip_CreateBitmap(Width, Height)
    hdc := Gdip_GetImageGraphicsContext(hbm)

    ; Copiar el contenido del thumbnail al bitmap
    DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties(hwndThumb, 0, 0, Width, Height, hdc)

    ; Guardar la captura de pantalla usando GDI+
    Gdip_SaveBitmapToFile(hbm, ScreenshotDestPath)

    ; Liberar recursos de la imagen y thumbnail
    Gdip_DeleteGraphics(hdc)
    Gdip_DisposeImage(hbm)
    DwmUnregisterThumbnail(hwndThumb)

    FileAppend("Captura de pantalla guardada en: " ScreenshotDestPath "n", LogFilePath)

    ; Ejecuta el script de Python para verificar las condiciones
    command := PythonPath . " `"" . PythonScriptPath . "`""
    FileAppend("Ejecutando comando: " command "n", LogFilePath)
    RunWait(command, , "Hide", &PythonPID)

    ; Leer el archivo de resultados de Python
    Result := FileRead("C:\Users\arted\OneDrive - unizar.es\Escritorio\AutoHardIsaac\resultado.txt")
    FileAppend("Resultado leído: " Result "n", LogFilePath)

    ; Si se encuentran las condiciones deseadas, pausar el script y esperar reactivación
    if (Result = "True")
    {
        Send("{Esc up}")
        Sleep(100)
        Send("{Esc down}")
        Sleep(100)
        
        FileAppend("Condiciones encontradas. Script pausado.n", LogFilePath)
        
        Pause()  ; Pausa el script y espera a que presiones F12 para reanudar
    }
    else
    {
        FileAppend("Condiciones no encontradas. Reiniciando run.n", LogFilePath)
        ; Reinicia la run manteniendo la tecla "R" presionada
        Send("{r down}")
        Sleep(1500)  ; Mantener "R" presionada por 1.5 segundos
        Send("{r up}")
    }
}

; Tecla para reactivar el script
F12::Pause()

CerrarGDIplus:
    Gdip_Shutdown(pToken)
    ExitApp()
Return

Tell me if you need the python script too or not, thanks!
I tried telling ChatGPT all the errors but it didn't fix any of them, it only sent me the same version again and again. I also tried searching for some documentation but I haven't been able to find it.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you actually use the OpenAI API, or have you just used ChatGPT?

I just used ChatGPT, I don't have the need for their API. Sorry for the bad tag, I wanted to write ChatGPT and it changed it to OpenAI-API xD
